# Can't bind to 'columnDefinitions' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-slickgrid'

Tags: angular-slickgrid

After installing Angular-Slickgrid I'm having the below issue. Can someone give me some clue? thanks.

[image]

My codes are below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-selection p-10">
  <div class="inner-card p-b-10 ">
    <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="dataset"></angular-slickgrid>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts
[image]

package.json
[image]

latest (2.17.11) angular-slickgrid having this issue
[image]

Comment: You should take a look at the [Angular-Slickgrid-Demos](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos) and clone it to get started.

Comment: @ghiscoding glad that you commented as the plugin Author. I'm using Angular 7.2.1. Can you suggest to me which Angular-Slickgrid version to use?

Comment: just use latest, it's all written on the readme

Comment: I have updated the Question. please check the last section.

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is, the only thing I can say about RxJS that I can on that line is that I use a specific version `^6.3.3` of RxJs. The newer version gives us some problem and I don't want to update, their signature is slightly different I think. So make sure to use the same version `"rxjs": "^6.3.3",` if that doesn't work I will say again please clone the Angular-Slickgrid-Demos and start from there